# Is it normal that an sql-server table has 60 columns, any better way to keep the data?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working in a transformer database for the company where I work.

I worked in the design and i get una table with 60 columns, i'm really new working on this, but i never get so much columns in the same table, is that normal?, is posible some kind of subcategorize inside the same table?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thanks so much and sory for my english :P

Comment: It could potentially indicate a poor schema/table design

Comment: And changing the DB schema could potentially break a lot of code. Just work with it.

Comment: B House, i use the normalization rules, but it keep getting in the same table

Comment: Thanks both, i gess i keep the design, is ugly, but i dont have any idea to separate without breaking some code

Comment: Whether something is normal or not is subjective, and not very helpful. I've worked with databases which had tables with 300+ columns, it's developers thought it very normal (and sensible too...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for a table to have those amount (60) of columns. However, it is also not usual.

It is always a good idea to separate the data into multiple tables where there is no ambiguity occurs. We call this process: **Normalization**. In this way, we can prevent any potential anomalies. Check the example below:

```
emp_id  emp_name  emp_address   emp_dept
101     John      London        D001
101     John      London        D002
123     Alex      Toronto       D300
166     Jack      Dubai         D900
166     Jack      Dubai         D004
```

Here, there are 2 "Jack"s. If we need to perform an update on `employee:101`, it would create an `update anomaly`.

We cannot insert any new data with a `null` emp_dept value if the column does not allow `null` values, which causes `insert anomaly.`

If department D300 is closed, then the department is removed from the DB then the employee Alex will be deleted here too, which will cause data loss and cause a `delete anomaly`.

A potential way to normalize the table above is to reorganize table by separating emp_id and emp_dept attributes like:

```
emp_id  emp_name  emp_address
101     John      London        
123     Alex      Toronto      
166     Jack      Dubai

emp_id  emp_dept
101       D001
101       D002
123       D300
166       D900
166       D004
```

This also helps memory by eliminating repeated data. Please check the website for more examples: https://beginnersbook.com/2015/05/normalization-in-dbms/